# How can I use JMeter to load SSH keys in Pageant

Tags: windows, jmeter, pageant

I'm trying to load in a pre-generated SSH key which is located in `%USERPROFILE%\\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk`.

I have User Defined Variables set:

```
PAGEANT: "C:\Path_to_pageant\Pageant.exe"
   HOME: %USERPROFILE%
 ID_RSA: ${HOME}\.ssh\id_rsa_jmeter.ppk
```

The OS Process Sampler is configured as:

```
Command: ${PAGEANT}
  Value: "${ID_RSA}"
```

After it runs, it shows:

```
Executing: "C:\Path_to_pageant\Pageant.exe" "${HOME}\.ssh\id_rsa_jmeter.ppk"
```

and Pageant alerts that it couldn't find the key, no key is loaded.

If I change ID_RSA to `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa_jmeter.ppk`:

```
Executing: "C:\Path_to_pageant\Pageant.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa_jmeter.ppk"
```

and Pageant alerts that it couldn't find the key, no key is loaded.

If I copy and paste that command into a command prompt, it will add the key to Pageant. 
It appears that neither `${HOME}` nor `%USERPROFILE%` is not being expanded.

Note: completely hard-coding the path will allow JMeter to import the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your

- `%USERPROFILE%`
  and
- `%HOME%`

variables with

- `${__BeanShell(System.getenv("USERPROFILE"),)}`
  and
- `${__BeanShell(System.getenv("HOME"),)}`

accordingly.

The approach above uses combination of [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) Java SDK class method call and JMeter's  [__Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function.

To learn what else can be done using Functions see [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series.

Answer (score 0):

It is only `%USERPROFILE%` that is failing to expand (`${HOME}` expands to `%USERPROFILE%`, which subsequently fails to expand).

It is because the expansion is done by the command prompt shell, but not by the OS process sampler.

Best way I can think to get the `%USERPROFILE%` would be to load it into a property at startup, then use the property in `${HOME}`

Add `-DUSERPROFILE=%USERPROFILE%` to your JMeter startup command line, then use `${__P{USERPROFILE}}` instead in the script.

Another alternative is to change your command, so that it runs `"cmd.exe /C \path_to_pageant\pageant.exe"`. This will call the command prompt to expand `%USERPROFILE%` before command prompt calls Pageant.